# How can I save and close AutoCAD application with python?

Tags: python, autocad, comtypes

I'm trying to save and close an AutoCAD application. I've tried to use `.Quit()` but didn't work.

```
from comtypes import COMError
from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetActiveObject


def main():
    # Capture opened AutoCAD
    try:
        acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")

    # Open new AutoCAD instance
    except (OSError, COMError):
        acad = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application", dynamic=True)

    # Path to dwg file
    filepath = r"C:\test.dwg"  # Replace it with the actual drawing path
    doc = acad.Documents.Open(filepath)

    load_lisp = '(load "C:/DemoExtracao.fas") '  # Notice that the last SPACE is equivalent to

    doc.SendCommand(load_lisp)

    execute_lisp = "(DEMO) "

    doc.SendCommand(execute_lisp)
    
    doc.Quit() # This line doesn't work


# Início da aplicação principal
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I save and close my AutoCAD application?

Comment: Using python `win32com`: [Saving AutoCAD files (.dwg) using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450655/saving-autocad-files-dwg-using-python). The answer also has links to AutoCad programming documentation.

Comment: But what about closing the AutoCAD application? At this question above I could just save as and save AutoCAD... =(

Comment: This methods works well in VBA, but not works in Python